# multi submit form

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How will i have a **form** having more than one **submit buttons**..? And how will i know in the **controller's action** that which **submit button** is clicked..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set various values of your submit buttons, so you will know which one was submitted. Like this:

```
<input type="submit" name="submit_btn" value="First submit" />
<input type="submit" name="submit_btn" value="Second submit" />
```

After that, check on the server-side when `submit_btn` equals "First submit" or "Second submit":

```
if params["submit_btn"] == "First submit"
    #Actions
else
    #Other actions
end
```

Comment: thnx for your help... BUT one thing is there that why it always get into the first condition..?

Comment: Try to write `params["submit_btn"]` instead of `params[:submit_btn]`. Try also to debug your action by using `p params`, maybe.